# Simple but long page is very slow in IE and quick elsewhere (long DOM causing problems?)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser

One of the pages served by my application is very long (about 8Mb of source HTML, mostly tables). I know this itself is a sign of wrong architecture but there are circumstances that don't allow to change that quickly :(

In almost every browser apart from IE the page is still fine - of course it's slower than an average one but it looks like the time it takes to display is mostly defined by code download speed, and I have no problems with that.

It is very different in IE (7, 8 and 9) though - the page is extremely slow for about 10-15 seconds after downloading with frozen screen effect, then experiences noticeable scrolling lags and "script is running slowly" messages while there is no javascript running on the page. IE9 takes about 800Mb of RAM as well when displaying that page.

When I serve plain text content of that size it is much better, but formatted HTML tables seem to be causing problems. It looks like long DOM is a blocker for IE of any version.

I don't know what answer am I hoping for - obviously a proper solution would be to change the page architecture by breaking it down on server side and serving piece by piece via ajax, but still - is there any kind of say magic pragma or js for IE to stop doing what it does with DOM tree speeding it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be the best solution to chuck page downloading by client. But you have to be advised that the `"table"` tag is the most slowest rendering tag in IE (as my experience says). So in the first step I think you should do some modifications on the HTML document. Here are some suggestions:

1. Clear inline style sheets and use css classes as far as you can. It will help your HTML document to be smaller in size.
2. use some other expressions instead of using TABLE. using DIV s would be my first recommendation. Simplify your document and the parser can read the codes as easy as you can. So make them easy to read. It causes to write less and again, it helps the document to be much smaller.
3. remove all the spaces, tabs, new line characters and many other extra contents from the HTML document.
4. Qualify the content you are presenting to be more useful for the client. As we all now, we can see two lines at most. So all the data on one page is not a good idea, actually useless. Because while user is downloading the document, some data might be updated on the server and the data your user has is not valid anymore.

After all, always remember that every character stores 8 bytes in the memory (no matter it's virtual or not) including all the parsing variables and memory uses by xml parsers and some how hard codes to load the HTML string and make a DOM out of it. The speed to read the document and parsing it is so important as much as the size would be.

Hope it helps you..
Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I wholeheartedly agree loading that much data on a single page is a bad practice. But that is a temporary solution which is going to be rewritten anyway one day, and it'd be a shame to re-write now it just to satisfy IE (as I mentioned, other major browsers are totally fine with it). Rewriting tables to divs might make sense, I'll accept the answer if that helps.

Comment: Hope it helps you. Cheers bro,,,

Comment: Tables were the blocker indeed . Adding fixed widths to columns and setting table-layout CSS property to 'fixed' improved the situation a lot.

Comment: Exactly. I just said that making the DOM model and reading it is one of the important parameters and should be easy for the parser to understand it. Any computations about any dynamic parameters such as widths, heights or any other layout things would decrease the performance a lot as you already experienced. Happy to hear that... Cheers